# TextArea cursor shape overlapping other items

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a `TextArea` and popup or another item which overlaps it. But when I pointing at popup, cursor shape doesn't change. I need the cursor to become default when I pointing to overlapped items.

[image: Screenshot]

**Code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Component.onCompleted: pop.open()

    TextArea {
        width: 800
        height: 600
    }

    Popup {
        id: pop
        Rectangle {
        color: "red"
        width: 100
        height: 100
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: If you're using Qt Quick Controls 2, try the latest Q 5.9 beta. The issue has been fixed by specifying explicit cursors for all interactive controls.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in Qt 5.9.
Thanks to [jpnurmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4666542/jpnurmi)

Answer (score 0):

The `TextArea` contains a `MouseArea` that sets a different cursor shape.
The cursor shape is always defined by the top-most `MouseArea`. Therefore the solution is, to add a `MouseArea` to the overlapping `Item` to reset the cursor shape for this area.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600


    TextArea {
        width: 800
        height: 600
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: 'red'
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 100
        y: 50

        MouseArea { // This resets the cursor shape, if the cursor hovers over the Rectangle
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you then please share a code example of your problem?

Comment: Thanks. I will check it, as soon as I am on my machine with Qt 5.8 again.